# What's the equivalent of Range.init?(_ range: NSRange, in string: String) in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need to implement this swift code in obj-c:

```
let string: String;
let match: NSTextCheckingResult;
...
if let uriRefrence = Range(match.range(at: .one), in: string) {
     ...
}
```

what's the equivalent of `Range.init?(_ range: NSRange, in string: String)` in obj-c?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/3126733-init

or how can I implement this?

Comment: You don't need this in Objective-C. You won't be using the Swift `Range` and `String` types in Objective-C. You'll use `NSRange` and `NSString`. Since `NSString` can be directly indexed with integers, you don't need this extra handling.

Comment: @Sweeper mhm I see. Could I ask you to write would be the objc code then? For the sake of clarity.

Comment: I'm not very good writing Obj-C syntax, but I think it would just be `NSRange uriReference = [match rangeAtIndex:1];`

Comment: Did it work? Should I post an answer?

Comment: eh unfortunately I can't tell you yet, because that's just part of a big rewriting. I need to debug until there first.